# Problem with Covariance Matrix through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function which returns the covariance of an array. I am given Stock Prices of 5 stocks in descending order from `2nd February 2017` to `8th July 2019`. I proceeded by finding their arithmetic returns. But after writing the code, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> gives me `#VALUE`.

```
Function VarCovArr(RNG As Range)
    Dim Arr()
    Dim OutputArr()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim ReturnArr()
    Dim WF As Object
    Dim TempArr()
    Dim TempArr2()

    Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Arr = RNG

   'Build Return Array
   '(1) Size of Array

    ReDim ReturnArr(LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) - 1, LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2))

    For i = LBound(ReturnArr, 1) To UBound(ReturnArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(ReturnArr, 2) To UBound(ReturnArr, 2)
            ReturnArr = Arr(i + 1, j) / Arr(i, j) - 1
        Next j
    Next i

    ReDim OutputArr(1 To UBound(Arr, 2), 1 To UBound(Arr, 2))
    ReDim TempArr(1 To UBound(ReturnArr, 1), 1 To UBound(ReturnArr, 1))
    ReDim TempArr2(1 To UBound(ReturnArr, 1), 1 To UBound(ReturnArr, 1))

    For i = LBound(OutputArr, 1) To UBound(OutputArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(OutputArr, 2) To UBound(OutputArr, 2)
            For k = LBound(ReturnArr, 1) To UBound(ReturnArr, 2)
                TempArr(k) = ReturnArr(k, i)
                TempArr2(k) = ReturnArr(k, j)

                '(2) Store Covariance matrix
                OutputArr(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covariance_S(TempArr, TempArr2)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    VarCovArr = OutputArr
End Function
```

Comment: You need to ask a question (see [ask]). Use a helper `Sub` to feed the `rng` parameter of your UDF. This way you can debug it step by step using F8.

Comment: According to [this](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/covariance-s-function/), one or both of your array might be empty